# Was the Batman statue in "Shazam!" a real piece of merch, or just a movie prop?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, props, shazam-2019, merchandise

In the movie *Shazam!*, there is a scene where, during Billy's first fight with Sivana, he winds up in a toy store and throws a plastic statue of Batman (which exclaims a recording stating "I'm Batman") at Sivana.

You can see it at 3:18 in [this clip](https://youtu.be/W4VEPq1QXVI?t=198) of the movie on YouTube.

Is this statue a real piece of DC merchandise, or was it just a movie prop that was made specifically for this scene in the movie? Some of the other items on the shelves in that scene seem to be DC merchandise in boxes labelled with the DC logo, so it seems possible that they're real, but I'm not sure and I can't find anything with a quick Google search.

[image: Shazam about to throw a 1-meter Batman figure]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This appears to be a *[Big-Figs Colossal DC Universe Batman 48.5″ Gotham Guardian Action Figure with Bat Signal Light](https://gamesplusinc.com/product/big-figs-colossal-dc-universe-batman-48-5-gotham-guardian-action-figure-with-bat-signal-light/)*

[image: A tall plastic Batman figure with the classic look: grey suit with black highlights on the gloves, pants, boots, cowl and cape wearing a yellow utility belt. It stands in a cut out box on the feet only]

Comment: Yeesh, at that size and price you'd think they could at least give the shoulders a decent range of motion... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Re, "decent range of motion..." But then it wouldn't be an "action figure" would it? It'd be a big old _doll_ instead. What true Batman fan would ever be caught playing with dolls?

Comment: Its not a doll, that's Batman - and says so himself!

Comment: Does it actually say "I'm Batman", or was that something the movie added in? The product page you linked to doesn't say anything about it having any recorded audio.

Comment: @nick012000 - It's got a projecting bat-signal (from the chest) which can be toned down to use as a nightlight, but there's no audio; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iN20SuZzSDI

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think you have that backwards.  Most "action figures" are very well articulated.  Many "dolls" aren't (although there are some well articulated ones too).  Also, might I direct you to the HasLab Sentinel and HasLab Unicron figures...

Answer (score 10):

It's real, though I can't locate the exact reference (yet).

The movie's director talked about the toy store scene for [CinemaBlend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2464934/there-were-some-dc-universe-references-shazam-wasnt-allowed-to-make), explaining that they couldn't use action figure of non-DCEU characters. Notably,

> No, they're all sort of real DC toys that are in there. I mean, some were like, 'Hey, you can't have that character, because that character's not in the universe yet. You have to stick to these characters.'